# Python 2: Replace word in string with icon image.

Tags: python, tkinter, label, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create a weather application. I have a section of code that retrieved weather information from DarkSkyAPI for the next 7 days. The String that is print out looks like `Sat clear-day 10`. What I am trying to do is display the text I'm a label but replace the `clear-sky` section of the string for the `clear-sky` icon I have.

Format I am looking for is `Sat {icon} 10`

```
from Tkinter import *
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import requests
import json

## Location of Icons used
icon_lookup = {
    'clear-day'             : "Icons/WeatherIcons/WeatherIcon.png",

}

class Weather(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg = 'black')

        self.iconLbl = Label(self, bg="black")
        self.iconLbl.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.icon = ''

        self.get_weather()

    def get_weather(self):
        try:
            ## Get Week's Weather Values
            todayPlusOne = 'Sat clear-day 10' 

            ## Get Icon
            icon_id = 'clear-day'
            icon2 = None
            if icon_id in icon_lookup:
                icon2 = icon_lookup[icon_id]

            if icon2 is not None:
                if self.icon != icon2:
                    self.icon = icon2
                    image = Image.open(icon2)
                    image = image.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
                    image = image.convert('RGB')
                    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

                    self.iconLbl.config(image=photo)
                    self.iconLbl.image = photo
            else:
                self.iconLbl.config(image='')


        except Exception as e:
            print "Error: %s. Cannot get weather." % e

        self.after(900000, self.get_weather)

class FullscreenWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.configure(background='black')
        self.topFrame = Frame(self.tk, background = 'black', height = 240)
        self.middleFrame = Frame(self.tk, background = 'black', height = 240)
        self.bottomFrame = Frame(self.tk, background = 'black', height = 240)
        self.topFrame.pack(side = TOP, fill = BOTH)
        self.middleFrame.pack(side = TOP, fill = BOTH)
        self.bottomFrame.pack(side = TOP, fill = BOTH)
        self.state = False
        self.tk.bind('<Return>', self.toggle_fullscreen)

        #weather
        self.weather = Weather(self.topFrame)
        self.weather.pack(side = LEFT, anchor = NW, padx = 25, pady = 25)

    def toggle_fullscreen(self, event=None):
        self.state = not self.state
        self.tk.attributes('-fullscreen', self.state)
        return 'break'      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = FullscreenWindow()
    w.tk.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    w.tk.geometry('720x480')
    w.tk.mainloop()
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put an image in the middle of text in a label; you can only put an image on one side (top, bottom, left, right) or centered. To have both text and an image you need to use the `compound` attribute of the label.

To have an image in the middle of text, there are at least three options:

1. create a frame with a label for the text, a label for the icon, and another label for more text
2. use a canvas, and create text and image items on the canvas
3. use a one-line text widget, which supports embedded images.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I've decided to go for option 1.